# I want to make a responsive carousel with different sized images

Tags: wordpress, slider, carousel, elementor

I want to make a responsive carousel but the images are in different sizes and I want to fit all images in their original size in equal height just like on this website https://storkandlens.com please someone help

I am using elementor I have tried many plugins but none of them providing the solution I want right now I am using media carousel element in elementor but it is looking like this https://storkandlens.cloudaccess.host/ images are zooming in instead of being in equal height and in their original size.

Comment: You should use images in the background.

Comment: Hello can you guide a little more?

Comment: Means you can show the images in a frame of code and image will be in background and fill in that.